# What's happening to my zebra finches?

Tags: medicines, diseases, birds

I had two young zebra finches, one female and one male, but the female started getting quite bloated and was staying more and more in a nest like thing we built for them. One day she just died in her nest. The male was still okay.

After, we bought a new female (from the same store), but now the same thing is happening to the male. Any idea what could be happening to them?

Comment: Best thing I can come up with is to go to the vet, if you can.